# get value of a list

Tags: javascript, html

>Enabled
      >Disabled

...

```
function my_field_change()
{
   var my_value = document.forms[0].my_field.value;
   ...
   if (dhcp_relay == "1") {
       document.forms[0].some_other_field.disabled = 1;
   }
   ...
}
```

In the function "my_field_change()" I'm expecting to have 'my_value' equal to either 1 or 0, bit it won't happen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you using `my_value` outside of setting it? Loosk like you want `dhcp_relay` set to 1, but I don't see where you use `my_value` otherwise... =/

Comment: Is your [select] within a [form] element? Just in case that is a problem, since document.forms obviously won't work without a form. If there is one, I find I have better luck referencing forms by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the value associated with the selected index:

```
var my_value = document.forms[0].my_field[document.forms[0].my_field.selectedIndex].value;
```

If you can't get that to work, another option is to update the html to use an id, and reference that id specifically in the javascript:

```
<select id="my_field" name="my_field" onChange="my_field_change();">
  <option value="1" <% nvram_match("my_field", "1", "selected"); %>>Enabled</option>
  <option value="0" <% nvram_match("my_field", "0", "selected"); %>>Disabled</option>
</select>
```

...

```
function my_field_change()
{
   var select = document.getElementById("my_field");
   var my_value = select[select.selectedIndex].value;
   ...
}
```

Comment: JGB146, I tried your suggestion, but doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Is your `<select>` block inside a `<form>`? I tested this myself and it works for me as long as that is the case.

Comment: @JGB146, the updated version doesn't work for me either, don't know what's going on with my system :(

Comment: @Eric Wendelin, yes the 'select' block is within 'form', I've double checked that.